# Tensorflow Eager name based vs object based saving

Tags: tensorflow

What is the difference between name based vs object based saving in Tensorflow Eager Execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TensorFlow has traditionally used global names for variables to match checkpointed values to variables in the graph. Basically just the `.name` property of a variable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
dense(tf.ones([1, 1]))
print(dense.variables[0].name)
```

Prints:

```
dense/kernel:0
```

This is the name [`tf.train.Saver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) writes to a checkpoint, and the key it uses to match the restored value. It works well when the Python program contains a single TensorFlow model, or when model building is isolated (as with [`tf.estimator.Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator), which builds the model it's wrapping from scratch in a new `Graph`).

Object-based checkpointing, [`tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint` / `tfe.Checkpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Checkpoint), aims to make this variable matching more robust when the Python program changes or when multiple TensorFlow models are used in the same Python program. It does this by building a dependency graph of objects with named edges and saving it with the checkpoint:

[image: visualization of the dependencies between objects in the TensorFlow eager GAN example]
(visualization from the [eager GAN example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/gan); black nodes are Layer objects, blue are variables, red are optimizers, and orange are slot variables created by optimizers)

These named dependencies are created automatically when assigning attributes to a [`Checkpointable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Checkpointable) object, including [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model). For example [`self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(...)` makes a dependency edge named "conv1" when `self` is a `tf.keras.Model`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/18f8568ca2e2efedd482e1120d4a5b73aab7841c/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/gan/mnist.py#L60).

When restoring, the structure of the model (the objects and their named edges) should match, not necessarily the exact names of the variables.

Going back to the `Dense` layer, we can make a checkpoint for it and then restore it into a second object whose variable names do not match:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
save_checkpoint = tfe.Checkpoint(dense=dense)
dense.variables[0].assign([[1., 2.]])
save_path = save_checkpoint.save("/tmp/tensorflow/ckpt")
# save_path="/tmp/tensorflow/ckpt-1"
```

Then when restoring, still in the same program:

```
second_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
restore_checkpoint = tfe.Checkpoint(dense=second_dense)
restore_checkpoint.restore(save_path)
second_dense(tf.ones([1, 1]))
print(second_dense.variables[0])
```

Prints:

```
<tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[1., 2.]], dtype=float32)>
```

The value `[[1., 2.]]` was restored before being used by the `Dense` layer (restore-on-create), and despite having a different name (`dense_1/kernel` instead of `dense/kernel`).

Although it's particularly helpful when executing eagerly, object-based saving works when graph building too. Just add `run_restore_ops()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe

dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
dense(tf.ones([1, 1]))

save_checkpoint = tfe.Checkpoint(dense=dense)
assign_op = tf.group(dense.variables[0].assign([[1., 2.]]),
                     dense.variables[1].assign([3., 4.]))

second_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
restore_checkpoint = tfe.Checkpoint(dense=second_dense)
second_dense(tf.ones([1, 1]))

with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(assign_op)
  save_path = save_checkpoint.save("/tmp/tensorflow/ckpt")
  restore_checkpoint.restore(save_path).assert_consumed().run_restore_ops()
  print(session.run(second_dense.variables[0]))
```

Prints:

```
[[1. 2.]]
```

Useful resources:

- Programmer's guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#object-based_saving
- Eager examples (those that write checkpoints use object-based saving): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples
- Documentation for `tfe.Checkpoint`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Checkpoint
- Documentation for the `tfe.Checkpointable` class which manages dependencies between objects: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/Checkpointable

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I noticed that if you do not run dense(tf.ones([1, 1])), dense will contains no variables which is quite different from Pytorch, why it is designed like this
? Only after a call then the layer can contains variables?

Comment: It is rather nice not to have to specify the input dimension, which along with the output dimension determines the variable's shape in most layers. I believe that's the main reason for having a separate build phase (which can be called manually). Also lets you configure a layer and then add the variables to the Graph it gets called in.